# How to modify html file before HTMLOutput in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, css, google-apps-script

I need to modify a html file in doGet() before HTMLOut.  But the html file has `<?!=include('css').getContent();?>`, which cannot be executed, and become part of HTML text.  Appreciate your help?  Here is the code.

```
function doGet(e) {
  var landingPage;
  landingPage=e.parameter.page ||'index';
  var html=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(landingPage);

  var content=html.getContent();
  content=content.replace("%%ToBeChanged%%","New Value");
  var html2=HtmlService.createTemplate(content);
  return html2.evaluate()
    .setTitle('testing Website')
    .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
}
```

Here is the index.html in the project

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />

   <title>TITLE</title>

   <?!=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('styleSheet').getContent(); ?>
    <?!=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('script').getContent(); ?>

</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <input type='text' value='##ToBeChanged##'>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the scriptlet you have a function name `include()`  I don't see any .gs server side code for `function include() {return theHtml}`  In the View menu, choose "Execution Transcript" after the code has run, and look at the bottom of the print out.  Is there a line number that failed?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to load the page with some CSS and JavaScript. You don't want to call the HTMLService in your HTML document. Try this-

Code.gs—

```
function doGet() {
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('LandingPage'); 
  return template.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

function include(filename) {
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent(); 
}
```

index.html-

```
<head>
<?!= include("StyleSheet"); ?>
</head>
```

Notice the doGet function says .create**TemplateFromFile**(), and not .createHtml**OutputFromFile**. OutputFromFile basically gets the data from the file, but doesn't process it. In other words it doesn't render/incorporate the StyleSheet or JavaScript files.

You can read more about how to set this up in the Google Apps Script Documentation under [Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices).

I hope it helps.